# replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject: Error

Tags: objective-c

Can someone see where the error is here...

```
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *inputStr = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *trimmedStr = [inputStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                               [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]; 
[[arr objectAtIndex:0] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:trimmedStr];
```

output:

```
-[__NSCFString replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68a8eb0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[__NSCFString replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68a8eb0'
```

EDIT: added extra line to show that the array has been declared and populated.
So as said in comment below, when I replace the line:

```
[[arr objectAtIndex:0] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:trimmedStr];
```

with:

```
[arr replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:trimmedStr];
```

Xcode error(before running):

```
 No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is whats wrong:

```
[[arr objectAtIndex:0] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:trimmedStr];
```

what you actually want to do is:

```
[arr replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:trimmedStr];
```

you were sending replaceObjectAtIndex to the string in the array ([arr objectAtIndex:0]) which obviously wont work out. Send that message to the (mutable) array and it'll replace the string with the new one.

For your next question: Tell us more about what you are trying to do etc, and dont limit yourself to less than 10 words. The more detail you give, the more help you will get.

Comment: That was what I had at first and I agree it makes more sense, but Xcode gives an error:
"No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject'.

Comment: because NSArray is immutable and does not know about changing its content. In fact `[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","]` returns such an immutable array and you won't be able to replace any item in there. If you want to modify that array, you will have to create a NSMutableArray from it using `-mutableCopy`.

Comment: @Julien yeah, it gave a warning when I changed the type to mutable, ran ok though.  +1 for mutableCopy. Thanks

Comment: The fact that it works just uncovers an implementation detail (it's not totally surprising `-componentsSeparatedByString:` uses a mutable array and returns it as it but this might change in the future and you will end up crashing.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not positive what you're trying to do (since I don't know what `arr` is), it would appear that you are getting an `NSString` object from your array and attempting to perform `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` on it. Perhaps you meant this instead:

```
[arr replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:trimmedStr];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of it, here is the correct fix:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy] autorelease];
NSString *inputStr = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *trimmedStr = [inputStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                           [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]; 
[arr replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:trimmedStr];
```

or, if you are using ARC:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
NSString *inputStr = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *trimmedStr = [inputStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                           [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]; 
[arr replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:trimmedStr];
```

Comment: +1 for the ARC and non-ARC, also like the mutableCopy being on the same line:)